# VBA where to move copy and paste in individual columns command

Tags: excel, vba

Overall I have a folder of workbooks where I got to copy them and paste them into one new workbook that I made. I changed the do while,

1st: I can't get the copy and paste command to work I keep getting mismatch error I can't quite figure it out.

Option Explicit

Sub CopyDataFromDump()

```
Dim SourceFolder As String



Dim Filename As String



Dim Wb As Workbook



Dim CopyFromSheet As Worksheet



Dim PasteToSheet As Worksheet



Dim LastRow As Long



' folder path where your workbooks are located



SourceFolder = "C:\Users\jschlautman\Desktop\Dump\"



Dim ws As Worksheet

                                Dim teststring As String

   





Dim oFSO As Variant



Dim oFolder As Variant



Dim oFile As Variant



Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)

Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject

Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject







For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

                               

                                teststring = oFile

                               

  Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile) 'open each workbook in the folder



'Set CopyFromSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(oFile) ' sheet from where you want to copy data
```

' Set PasteToSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' sheet from where you want to paste data

```
    'CopyFromSheet.UsedRange.Copy   ' Copy data from the specified sheet in the opened workbook



   ' LastRow = PasteToSheet.Cells(PasteToSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1     ' Find the last row in the paste sheet



   ' PasteToSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  ' Paste data into the destination sheet in the active workbook



   ' Wb.Close False  ' Close the opened workbook



Next oFile
```

End Sub